# VBScript: Resort String and group with new Split Item

Tags: vbscript, split, grouping

> 'I Have the below String.. that splited with "#"

```
myStr = "78,6$25,01|25,02|25,03|25,04#74,5$15,01|15,02|15,03|15,04#70,1$25,06|25,07|25,08|25,09#77,3$25,07|25,08|25,09|25,10#78,2$10,05|10,06|10,07|10,08"
```

> 'And I want resort to this New String with New Grouping...
>
> 'i should group splited string with first value after dollar($) chrachter
>
> **But i dont know how should I Sorting and Grouping to new desired result**:

```
myStrDesired = "78,2$10,05|10,06|10,07|10,08@74,5$15,01|15,02|15,03|15,04@78,6$25,01|25,02|25,03|25,04#70,1$25,06|25,07|25,08|25,09#77,3$25,07|25,08|25,09|25,10"
```

> My Script:

```
Function GroupArrays()
  myStr = "78,6$25,01|25,02|25,03|25,04#74,5$15,01|15,02|15,03|15,04#70,1$25,06|25,07|25,08|25,09#77,3$25,07|25,08|25,09|25,10#78,2$10,05|10,06|10,07|10,08"

  'And I want resort to this New String with New Grouping...
  'i should group splited string with first value after dollar($) chrachter

  myStrDesired = "78,2$10,05|10,06|10,07|10,08@74,5$15,01|15,02|15,03|15,04@78,6$25,01|25,02|25,03|25,04#70,1$25,06|25,07|25,08|25,09#77,3$25,07|25,08|25,09|25,10"

  arrMyStr = Split(myStr,"#")
  arrMyStrDesired = ""
  for i = 0 to UBound(arrMyStr)
    ' find group id from each string
    groupVal = Split(Split(arrMyStr(i),"$")(1),",")(0)

    ' put the same groups together and split them by "#" And finally the isolation of other disciplines with "@"

      arrMyStrDesired = arrMyStrDesired & arrMyStr(i)
  next

  GroupArrays = arrMyStrDesired

End Function
```

> **New Description:***
>
> 1. Split the main String by "#".
> 2. In the each parts splited... see the first value after "$" and name to "groupId". (it is Important parameter for Grouping and sorting)
> 3. All of each parts has same groupId should be placed side by side and Joined by "#".
> 4. After above Steps... we should Join All New strings with other groupId by "@".... same as ... (00$01,05#01,06#...@02,07@03,4.....)

Comment: Is the answer to my question too hard?
I thought that I am very beginner.

Comment: I've looked at this question several times and find that the wording is fairly confusing. I *think* that you want to split on `#`, sort the resulting array with a custom sort order determined by the value after `$`, then rejoin them with `#` -- but the wording is quite obscure if that is what you want.

Comment: @John Coleman: I'm sorry for bad wording...plz see to new desc added after Function

Comment: Where did the `@` come from in the desired string? Is that a typo for `#`? Your original string doesn't have `@` in it

Comment: yes original string doesnot "@"... we should create this for split the Non-Group Strings

Comment: Where are you Mr @Ansgar Wiechers?! I know you can....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work on any Windows machine with the Dot Net runtime. If for some reason you don't have that -- would need a custom sort:

```
myStr = "78,6$25,01|25,02|25,03|25,04#74,5$15,01|15,02|15,03|15,04#70,1$25,06|25,07|25,08|25,09#77,3$25,07|25,08|25,09|25,10#78,2$10,05|10,06|10,07|10,08"

myDesiredStr = "78,2$10,05|10,06|10,07|10,08@74,5$15,01|15,02|15,03|15,04@78,6$25,01|25,02|25,03|25,04#70,1$25,06|25,07|25,08|25,09#77,3$25,07|25,08|25,09|25,10"

Function GroupVal(group)
    A = Split(group,"$")
    B = Split(A(1),",")
    GroupVal = CInt(B(0))
End Function

Function ReSort(str)
    Set D = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set keyList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    groups = Split(str,"#")
    For i = 0 to UBound(groups)
        group = groups(i)
        v = GroupVal(group)
        If D.Exists(v) Then
            D.Item(v) = D.Item(v) & "#" & group
        Else
            D.Add v,group
            keyList.Add v
        End If
    Next

    keyList.Sort()
    newGroups = Array()
    ReDim newGroups(Ubound(groups))
    i = -1
    For Each v In keyList
        i = i + 1
        newGroups(i) = D.item(v)
    Next
    ReDim Preserve newGroups(i)
    Resort = Join(newGroups,"@")
End Function

MsgBox myDesiredStr = Resort(myStr)
```

The msgbox pops up `True`

Comment: Thank you very match mr @John Coleman.
You did me a big favor.